# PIR motion switch

Tags: arduino, switches, pir

I have been thinking to use a PIR motion **switch** (originally the switch is aim to open light and used as switch for big current.
I saw in the detector specification that:
Rated load: 300-1200W

So if I am using this switch for my Ardruino I cannot read the detector data? because the Arduino power consumption is much less than 300[Watt].

So my question is it possible to use this IR switch for input to Arduino controller?

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: I Upvoted this. Do not get me wrong. +1 because this is an important warning example on how programming has climbed to the top of the electricity skills. Unfortunately the need of understanding the good old basics has gone nowhere if one wants to stay alive with the electricity. No software rebuilds the burned houses nor revitalizes the dead bodies.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't supplied a datasheet for the switch (and you should have) but from your description that is a mains-powered switch for switching a mains-powered lamp.

The output of that switch will most likely be full mains voltage when on. This will destroy your micro-controller and present a serious shock hazard.

You need to purchase one of the sensors designed for low-voltage operation such as the ones sold for Arduino projects.

[image]

Comment: Also, based on the minimum wattage requirement, the sensor probably powers itself through the load (no neutral wire) so it isn't even practical to use a relay to interface to the micro. Agreed, get the right sensor.

Comment: thanks, but the low voltage sensor does not have long distance sensitivity. the generic PIR switch has 12m long distance recognition.
So I need the low voltage with long distance, is there something fit to me?

Comment: Yes, but you'll have to search for it yourself.